# Joining a previously filtered table with another and setting nulls if there is no such stored data

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with the following problem: I have two tables, like these:

**Table foo**

```
id      some_unimportant_data
1234    'some string'
5678    'some other string'
```

**Table bar**

```
id    timestamp     status
1234  1234567890    pending
1234  1234567891    canceled
```

Some id's in the *foo* table may have some related fields in the *bar* table or they possible may have none. I'm trying to filter the *bar* table by unique id's with latest timestamps and get its status and then join it with the *foo* table.

The resulting table needs to be with corellating data from the *bar* table if it has some, and in the other case the data in field status has to be of the type null.

I managed to filter and join, but I can't quiet grasp how to join fields in two tables without corellating data.

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT
    foo_table.id,
    bar_table.timestamp,
    bar_table.status
FROM [foo_location] AS foo_table
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, status, max(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM [bar_location]
    GROUP BY id, status) as bar_table
ON foo_table.id == bar_table.sku_id
```

So the result for the examples above should look like:

```
id    timestamp    status       some_unimportant_data
1234  1234567891   'canceled'   'some string'
5678  NULL         NULL         'some other string'
```

Much obliged for any advice!

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause. What do you get?

Comment: In your example `1234` is both `pending` and `cancelled`.  Is your problem that you don't know how to pick the latest record for each `id`?  *(If so, you need to specify if this is `MySQL` or `SQL Server` or `Oracle`, etc, etc.)*

Comment: Actually, removing the WHERE clause did exactly the right thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT f.id, b.timestamp, b.status
FROM foo_location f LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [bar_ocation b
     ) b
     ON f.id = b.id AND seqnum = 1;
```